# QProcess, Debian и команда с "параметрами"

Tags: qt5, debian, linux

netstat -n | awk '{print $5}' Простая конструкции выводит ip:port - отлично отрабатывает.

При попытке:

> ```
> process.start("netstat -n | awk '{print $5}'");
> process.waitForFinished();
>
> QByteArray result = process.readAll();
> ```

получаю кукишь, netstat -n отработала, но awk не подхватило, получил просто вывод команды netstat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логично команда отработала. QProcess выполняет один процесс, а Вы пытаетесь выполнить последовательность. На [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701504/command-working-in-terminal-but-not-via-qprocess) этот случай разбирается и объясняется.

Кратко - нужно запустить шелл и передать ему набор команд.

P.S. указанная Вами команда возвращает не только набор ip:port, а и `State`, `DGRAM`,`SEQPACKET`, `STREAM` и многое другое. (OS: Fedora 20).